# How to remove document click event handlers added by ngx-bootstrap dropdownToggle?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am using ngx-bootstrap v1.9.1 and working on Angular 2. I found that change detection is getting fired for my whole application on every click at any place in my document. (Just did a console log to in `ngDoCheck()` of my App Component). On inspecting the event listeners in the browser I found multiple `click` listeners are added on the `document`. When the number of rendered components increase these click handlers cause huge change detections to occur making the application super slow.

By the method of elimination, I found that it is the `dropdownToggle` directive that is attaching document click handlers. On referring the [docs](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/old/1.9.1/#/dropdowns#config) for ngx-bootstrap, I find that they provide a configuration where the dropdown will not close If I click anywhere else on the document.

```
providers: [{provide: BsDropdownConfig, useValue: {autoClose: false}}]
```

This works just fine, just for the fact that dropdown doesn't close if I click somewhere else on the document, but the event listeners attached to the document still exist so my whole issue is still the same! Anywhere I click on the screen change detection is getting fired.

Is there any way in which I can remove those handlers while keeping the use of dropdownToggle? Or should I resort to custom dropdowns itself?